# Cannot retrieve GraphQL schema via graphql.macro loader in Mocha tests

Tags: node.js, graphql, mocha.js

I have trouble with retrieving GraphQL schema in my Mocha/ChaiJS tests.

Our project's client uses graphql.macro loader to get schemas.

`const GET_REGIONS_QUERY = loader('../../../graphql/queries/object/getRegions.graphql');`

I am testing backend performing requests directly to graphql.
Tests are located in the client module `./client/test/api`.

My test looks like:

```
import { loader } from 'graphql.macro';

const schema = loader('../../src/graphql/queries/object/getList.graphql');

  it('Does something...', async () => {
    const res = await graphqlRequest.post('')
      .set({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${user.accessToken}`,
      })
      .send({
        query: schema,
        variables: getObjectsListVariables(user.id),
      });
  });
```

BUT, `loader` returns me an empty object :(
However, it works well in `/src` where are webpack, appolo client and other stuff...
Please help!

Comment: SOLVED by adding `"babel-plugin-macros"` into the .babelrc